# better way to get the last character in a string in f#

Tags: string, f#

I want the last character from a string

I've got `str.[str.Length - 1]`, but that's ugly. There must be a better way.

Comment: Why is that ugly? Are you looking for something like str.LastChar()?

Comment: I was hoping for something like 'str last'

Comment: There isn't a better way (unless you write your own)

Comment: The similarities with Python made me want something like `str.[-1:]`; however, such a syntax would introduce one of the weaknesses of Python to C#: incentivizing computationally expensive operations by making them pretty.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There's no better way to do it - what you have is fine.

If you really plan to do it a lot, you can author an F# extension property on the string type:

```
let s = "food"

type System.String with
    member this.Last =
        this.Chars(this.Length-1)  // may raise an exception

printfn "%c" s.Last
```

Answer (score 7):

This could be also handy:

```
let s = "I am string"
let lastChar = s |> Seq.last
```

Result:

```
val lastChar : char = 'g'
```

Answer (score 3):

(This is old question), someone might find this useful, orig answer from Brian.

```
type System.String with

    member this.Last() =
        if this.Length > 1 then 
            this.Chars(this.Length - 1).ToString()
        else 
            this.[0].ToString()
    member this.Last(n:int)  =
        let absn = Math.Abs(n)
        if this.Length > absn then
            let nn = 
                let a = if absn = 0 then 1 else absn
                let b = this.Length - a
                if b < 0 then 0 else b
            this.Chars(nn).ToString()
        else 
            this.[0].ToString()
```

---

"ABCD".Last()    ->  "D"

"ABCD".Last(1)   ->  "D"

"ABCD".Last(-1)  ->  "D"

"ABCD".Last(2)   ->  "C"

Answer (score 2):

You could also treat it as a sequence, but I'm not sure if that's any more or less ugly than the solution you have:

```
Seq.nth (Seq.length str - 1) str
```

Answer (score 1):

With .Net 8/F# 8, when language preview is enabled, there is support for indexing from the end of an array.

```ml
"Food"[^0] |> printfn "%c"  // -> d
```

Details are in [RFC 1076](https://github.com/fsharp/fslang-design/blob/main/preview/FS-1076-from-the-end-slicing.md)

To enable language preview see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/whats-new/fsharp-47), in short add a LangVersion element to the project file's property group:

```xml
    <PropertyGroup>
        <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
        <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
        <LangVersion>preview</LangVersion>
    </PropertyGroup>
```